# Can the product of a diagonal and orthogonal matrix always be written as a product of the same orthogonal matrix and a symmetric matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

Take any diagonal matrix $D$ and orthogonal matrix $Q$.  I feel intuitively confident that there exists a symmetric matrix $S$ such that the following identity holds

$$
DQ = QS
$$

The intuition comes from geometric interpretation: a diagonal matrix is an axes-aligned scaling, an orthogonal matrix is a rotation and/or reflection, and a symmetric matrix is a scaling aligned with some orthogonal basis (not necessarily the axes).  So when you write these as composed transformations

$$
T_1(\mathbf{x}) = DQ\mathbf{x} \\
T_2(\mathbf{x}) = QS\mathbf{x}
$$

it feels obvious that, for any given $D$ and $Q$, one should be able to find an $S$ that makes the two transformations equivalent.

But I'm having trouble showing that symbolically.

Comment: $Q^TDQ$ is symmetric, since $(Q^TDQ)^T=Q^TD^TQ=Q^TDQ$. For real matrices, take $S=Q^TDQ$. Since, for real matrices, $Q^T=Q^{-1}$. Then $QS=DQ$.

Comment: Thank you @egorovik.  Your double equality  $(^)^=^^=^$ is really nice and simple.  I wish I'd thought of trying that sooner!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm. I think I realized what's going on as I hit the submit button.  If one left multiplies both sides of the first equation by $Q^T$, then we arrive at a familiar looking expression:

$$
D Q = Q S \\
Q^T D Q = Q^T Q S \\
Q^T D Q = S
$$

which looks like the eigenvalue decomposition.  And the eigenvalues for a symmetric matrix are orthogonal.  So for a fixed diagonal $D$ and  orthogonal $Q$, one can choose the symmetric $S$ for whom the diagonal elements of $D$ are the eigenvalues, and the rows of $Q$ (columns of $Q^T$) are the eigenvectors.

Comment: It's true I didn't directly invoke $D^{-1}$, but I thought the eigenvalue decomposition implicitly required nonsingular $D$ and $S$.  I could be wrong though!

Comment: @kdbanman The zero matrix has an orthonormal eigenbasis. For a nontrivial example, take the matrix of any degenerate quadric.

Comment: Gotcha!  I’ll remove the part about nonsingular then - thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ symmetric matrices.

(1) If $A$ is positive definite, there exists a nonsingular matrix $Q$ such that $Q'AQ = I$ and $Q'BQ = D$, where $D$ is a diagonal matrix, and the diagonal elements of $D$ are the roots $λ$ of the polynomial equation $|B-2A| = 0$.

(2) If $A$ and $B$ are both nonnegative (neither has to be positive definite), there exists a nonsingular matrix $Q$ such that $Q'AQ$ and $QBQ$ are each diagonal.